# Why does Error 500 Web Api JWT authentication on the server?

Tags: c#, rest, api

I have the following method to authenticate the user with JWT

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] Usuario usuario)
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(usuario.Email, usuario.Password, isPersistent: false, lockoutOnFailure: false);
     if (result.Succeeded)
     {
         return BuildTokenAsync(usuario);
     }
         else
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
     }
}

private IActionResult BuildTokenAsync(Usuario usuario)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.UniqueName, usuario.Email),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Llave_super_secreta"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1);

        JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
           issuer: "https://mydomain",
           audience: "https://mydomain",
           claims: claims,
           expires: expiration,
           signingCredentials: creds);

        return Ok(new
        {
            token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            expiration = expiration
        });

    }
}
```

In localhost there is no problem, it's okay to send me the token.

[Result in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTo3O.png)

But in the service, the error 500 appears.

[Result in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrNdy.png)

If I send a call to another service on the server, there is no problem. All is well, just to authenticate I have the problem.

The server has the SSL certificate.

[Server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXWNy.png)

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The solution is that the environment variables are not being passed to the server